# Simple update query, is returning error

Tags: sql

Ran a query:

```
select * from comm_list where comm_id = 'XXX' and comm_fp_group_id = 'YYY'
```

updating:

```
update comm_list set comm_fp_group_id = 'ZZZ' 
where comm_id = 'XXX' and comm_fp_group_id = 'YYY'
```

returns:

> Update or insert of view or function 'comm_list' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Searched this site and ran other google searches and the information im getting is not clicking with me, im still not understanding...

Comment: Hint: Updating view(not table). Check view definition. Probably `join` or `computed columns`

Comment: Search for **`UPDATEable views`**. Check [remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx). `You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:  ....`

Comment: I am looking into this now. ty.